# Replacing matching strings from array keys in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

My goal here is to, within a string, find a supposed array's keys and in that string, replace these keys with the matching keys from the array.

I have a small, useful function that finds all my strings between 2 delimiters (sandbox link: https://repl.it/repls/UnlinedDodgerblueAbstractions):

```
function findBetween( $string, $start, $end )
{
    $start = preg_quote( $start, '/' );
    $end = preg_quote( $end, '/' );

    $format = '/(%s)(.*?)(%s)/';

    $pattern = sprintf( $format, $start, $end );

    preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );

    $number_of_matches = is_string( $matches[2] ) ? 1 : count( $matches[2] );

    if( $number_of_matches === 1 ) {
        return $matches[2];
    }

    if( $number_of_matches < 2 || empty( $matches ) ) {
        return False;
    }

    return $matches[2];
}
```

Example:

```
findBetween( 'This thing should output _$this_key$_ and also _$this_one$_ so that I can match it with an array!', '_$', '$_')
```

Should return an array with the values `['this_key', 'this_one']` as it does. Question is, how can I take these and replace them with an associative array's values?

Assume my array is this:

```
[
    'this_key' => 'love',
    'this_one' => 'more love'
];
```

My output should be this:

`This thing should output love and also more love so that I can match it with an array!`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that might be more readily solved with [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) than regex. We can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map) to add the `$start` and `$end` values around the keys of `$replacements`, and then use `strtr` to do the substitution:

```
$str = 'This thing should output _$this_key$_ and also _$this_one$_ so that I can match it with an array!';
$replacements = [
    'this_key' => 'love',
    'this_one' => 'more love'
];
$start = '_$';
$end = '$_';
$replacements = array_combine(array_map(function ($v) use ($start, $end) { return "$start$v$end"; }, array_keys($replacements)), $replacements);
echo strtr($str, $replacements);
```

Output:

```
This thing should output love and also more love so that I can match it with an array!
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/QCJSb)

If performance is an issue because you have to regenerate the `$replacements` array each time, this loop is much faster:

```
foreach ($replacements as $key => $value) {
    $new_reps["_\$$key\$_"] = $value;
}
```

Performance comparison [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uP97b)

Comment: Yo! This is the way to go. Can you explain a bit what's going on here?

Comment: @DanielM take a look at the manual for `strtr`, it has a form in which it can take an array of replacements. What I've done is use `array_map` to convert the replacements array to look like `[
    '_$this_key$_' => 'love',
    '_$this_one$_' => 'more love'
]` and then `strtr` goes over the string making the replacements as described in that array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I can see what it's doing, but I've tested and @Julio's answer is way, way faster.

Comment: @DanielM that surprises me a lot. I would expect `strtr` to be much faster than any form of `preg_replace`, and especially one with the overhead of a function call for every match.

Comment: At the same time, this function does parse arrays 3 times and each higher-level parse gets harder the more items there are in the lower ones, all while `preg_replace` only does a loop internally afaik.

Comment: @DanielM you only need to generate the replacements array once though, and it could certainly be written a lot more optimally than I did. My testing shows that the actual replacements are more than twice as fast using `strtr` than `preg_replace`: https://3v4l.org/el6qa

Comment: @DanielM I've added a new version of the code that generates the replacements array to my answer as well as a link to another performance demo. This significantly outperforms preg_replace.

Comment: Note also that you could simply generate the replacements array in that form to begin with and completely save the time re-generating it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
<?php

$str = 'This thing should output _$this_key$_ and also _$this_one$_ so that I can match it with an array!';

$replacements = [
    'this_key' => 'love',
    'this_one' => 'more love'
];

$replaced = preg_replace_callback('/_\$([^$]+)\$_/', function($matches) use ($replacements) {
    return $replacements[$matches[1]];
}, $str);

print $replaced;
```

You have a demo [here](https://www.ideone.com/JSoqgQ).

**The regular expression, explained:**

```
_              # Literal '_'
\$             # Literal '$' ($ needs to be scaped as it means end of line/string)
(              # Begin of first capturing group
    [^$]+      # One carcter that cannot be "$", repeated 1 or more times
)              # End of first capturing group
\$             # Literal '$'
_              # Literal '_'
```

For every match, the matching data (`$mathces`) is passed to the function.

On the first element of the array there is the first capturing group, that we use to do the replacement.

Comment: Hey Julio! Can you tell me how does this compare to @Nick's answer?

Comment: I actually just went ahead and tested this. Yours is way faster than Nick's. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: They both work! I just put another alternative using a different approach :) Beware of benchmarking though, unless you are using huge data, benchmarks may be useless. Also, unless performance is critial, I would just use the solution that is easiert to read/mantain.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this resolves your answer to the question !

```
$items['this_key'] = 'love';
$items['this_one'] = 'more love';

$string = 'This thing should output _$this_key$_ and also _$this_one$_ so that I can match it with an array!';

$this_key = $items['this_key'];
$this_one = $items['this_one'];
$string = str_replace('_$this_key$_',$this_key,$string);
$string = str_replace('_$this_one$_',$this_one,$string);

echo  $string;
```